# Class cannot directly extends Enum Class

Tags: java

I have public final class i.e., Public final Class BiometricPosition extends Enum, but it gives error like Class cannot directly extends java.lang.Enum.

Comment: Please post what (the code) you have so far.

Comment: And please tell what you want to achieve.

Comment: Please provide the requirements of your achievement. That why do you want to extend Enum.. This can be achieved in some other way.

Comment: Using words such as "urgent" in your question is not encouraged in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use?

```
public enum BiometricPosition { 
    ENUM_VALUE_1,
    ENUM_VALUE_2;
}
```

Then you can declare a variable like that:

```
BiometricPosition pos = BiometricPosition.ENUM_VALUE_1
```

And this is a very useful link for you:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Comment: Thank u for ur reply..Actually its not working please tell me any another way..

Comment: @Madhuri Can you explain what "not working" means?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`enum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) keyword to declare your class:

```
public enum BiometricPosition {
    ...
}
```

This will implicitly extend the special [`Enum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) class, as well as allow enum-specific syntax within the class body.

Comment: Thank u for ur answer but its not working ,its giving errors like everymethod in that class is already defined..

Comment: We're not psychics. Show your code, and the error messages.

Comment: @Madhuri It doesn't for me for any of the code examples.